# Is there any way to call the Windows Native API functions from the user mode?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, nt-native-api

I want to call some Native API function from the user mode with C++.
I was wondering if it is possible to circumvent the Windows API interface
completely and call directly the Native API functions from the user mode.

If possible then any code examples will be really helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it is possible, as all functions are exposed `ntdll.dll`. However you would need to write your own header file for those API functions you want to use. There is no official documentation on the NT API and it is not really meant to be used directly. But it is possible.

[Here](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=91) is a starting point.